# Copy & Paste error "Action can't work on multiple sections"

Tags: vba, error-handling, copy-paste

I am trying to paste the filtered results another column in the corresponding cells. When I try to paste I get the error "Action can't work on multiple sections". Any idea how to fix the code?

```
LRow = Ws1.Range("CJ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set PasteRng = Ws1.Range("F1:F" & LRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Ws1.Range("CJ1:CJ" & LRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
PasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I tested it and it gave the result I think you expect. The problem I think you are having is that some cells might be merged. Try it on a clean sheet.

Comment: I was still getting errors with it even on a clean sheet. I ended up changing the formula in cells inputted into CJ and just copy and pasting the entire column and now it works great. Thank you though!